# How to extract numbers enclosed in angle brackets in a string that might have numbers

Tags: perl

I want to extract the numbers within angle brackets only in a string that can contain numbers as well.

I have a string $sig = wrp1<0:4> and i want to only extract the numbers enclosed in the angle brackets. 
I tried @range_nums=$sig=~/(\d+)/g; unfortunately this gives me 1 0 4...which means it also extracted the 1 in front of the wrp1 which is not what i want because it deletes all the non-digit characters...i wanted it to treat "wrp1" as a word.

```perl
my $sig = wrp1<0:4>;
@range_nums = $sig =~/(\d+)/g; ## extracts 1 0 4 but i want only 0 and 4. Please NOTE $sig can be also wrp<0:4> for example. key is to just extract the numbers in the angle bracket.
```

0 4 is expected

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there's only one range:

```
my $sig = 'wrp1<0:4>';
@range_nums = $sig =~/<(\d+):(\d+)>/;
```

Comment: Thanks! My work around before your answer was to return the last 2 elements of the array using splice from my initial solution. I need to read up more on regex because i didn't think that would return the needed value. So basically it matches the digits using the regex specified only and only returns the numbers? Intuitively, this is hard to understand why without reading up on perl regex specifically.

Comment: The regex matches all the bits detailled in it, including the <, : and >. The bits within parentheses () are captures and in list context, are returned as a list.